# getAddress.io API Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the output of line_1 line_2 and line_3 all on the same field called "address" instead of them all being on there own input field.

I am using the API from getAddress.io and the code i am using is below, i have tried to the best of my knowledge and hitting my head against the wall and need some assistance from the professionals :)

At the moment using that code is shows addreses like below:

Line 1: Flat 14
Line 2: Linden Court
Line 3: Main Street

What i am trying to do is get the output on the same line like below:

Address: Flat 14, Linden Court, Main Street

```
$('#postcode_lookup').getAddress({
  api_key: 'MYAPIKEY',
  output_fields: {
    line_1: '#address',
    line_2: '#line2',
    line_3: '#line3',
    post_town: '#town',
    county: '#county',
    postcode: '#postcode'
  },
  onAddressSelected: function(elem, index) {
    let postcode = $('#getaddress_input').val();
    $('#postcode').val(postcode.toUpperCase());
  }
});
```

Comment: Please give a link to the documentation of whatever SDK/library you are using there.

Comment: The link to there site with the demo code above that i am using is: https://getaddress.io/#demo-section

Comment: also please show us the HTML into which you are placing this output.

Comment: Such a demo on its own doesn’t really tell us what is, and what isn’t possible using this library. The actual documentation should explain that. If there isn’t any, and trying the obvious (specify the same selector for multiple fields, and see what happens?) does not yield success either - then you might need to handle this yourself, in one of the callback functions.

Comment: or it might be simply the case that you need to output the variables into some inline elements instead of block-level or form elements. `<span id="address"></span><span id="line2"></span>`...etc

Comment: I have been told by the support team at https://getaddress.io/Documentation that it is possible with a callback functions but that is as far as my knowledge goes and has brought me here as suggested by them. sorry i cannot be of any much help

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass `elem` into your div:

```
onAddressSelected: function(elem,index){
    $('#postcode').val(elem);
}
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/semh9bv3/

You can separate the address by the commas but I don't know how accurate this will be:

```
let address = elem.split(',');
let line1 = address[0];
let line2 = address[1];
let line3 = address[2];
let town = address[3];
let county = address[4];
let postcode = address[5];
$('#postcode').val(line1 + line2 + line3);
```

See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1gpxuzL2/

For your code, it will be like this with my updates:

```
$('#postcode_lookup').getAddress({
  api_key: 'cHCcb9duOU6-o9q1F3-9JQ19989',
  output_fields: {
    line_1: '#address',
    line_2: '#line2',
    line_3: '#line3',
    post_town: '#town',
    county: '#county',
    postcode: '#postcode'
  },
  onAddressSelected: function(elem, index) {
    let address = elem.split(',');
    let line1 = address[0];
    let line2 = address[1];
    let line3 = address[2];
    let town = address[3];
    let county = address[4];
    let postcode = address[5];
    $('#postcode').val(line1 + line2 + line3);
  }
});
```

See updated fiddle with your code here https://jsfiddle.net/50kfnyo8/

Comment: That works however is shows the county and post town too, is there a way to just limit it to show line1 line 2 and line 3 ?

Comment: See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1gpxuzL2/. I wouldn't recommend this, as this will separate the address returned by the commas. I'd recommend using their API directly and pick and choose what you want.

Comment: Perfect!! that works great, however i have this code currently in the "onAddressSelected:" box so how can i but both the below code and your new code in the same part of the code if you get me.   onAddressSelected: function(elem,index){

    let postcode = $('#getaddress_input').val();

     $('#postcode').val(postcode.toUpperCase());

    }

Comment: How can I get the country?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the source code of the JS to explore more options, some docs would be fine anyway..

```
f = {
        api_key: "",
        output_fields: {
            line_1: "#line1",
            line_2: "#line2",
            line_3: "#line3",
            post_town: "#town",
            county: "#county",
            postcode: "#postcode"
        },
        api_endpoint: u,
        input: undefined,
        $input: undefined,
        input_label: "Enter your Postcode",
        input_muted_style: "color:#CBCBCB;",
        input_class: "",
        input_id: "getaddress_input",
        input_name: "getaddress_input",
        button: undefined,
        $button: undefined,
        button_id: "getaddress_button",
        button_label: "Find your Address",
        button_class: "",
        button_disabled_message: "Fetching Addresses...",
        $dropdown: undefined,
        dropdown_id: "getaddress_dropdown",
        dropdown_select_message: "Select your Address",
        dropdown_class: "",
        $error_message: undefined,
        error_message_id: "getaddress_error_message",
        error_message_postcode_invalid: "Please recheck your postcode, it seems to be incorrect",
        error_message_postcode_not_found: "Your postcode could not be found. Please type in your address",
        error_message_default: "We were not able to your address from your Postcode. Please input your address manually",
        error_message_class: "",
        lookup_interval: 1e3,
        debug_mode: !1,
        onLookupSuccess: undefined,
        onLookupError: undefined,
        onAddressSelected: undefined,
        sort_numerically: !0
    };
```